# How to use Blazor ValidationMessage on properties made from custom objects

Tags: c#, validation, blazor, data-annotations

How do we make the ValidationMessageFor include the child objects when validating?

My classes look like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "";
        FavoriteGame = "";
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Person's name is required and must not be empty.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FavoriteGame { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Name = "";
        Game = "";
        Coach = new Person();
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Team name is required and must not be empty.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Game { get; set; }

    public Person Coach { get; set; }
}
```

And my Blazor EditForm looks like this:

```
<EditForm Model="@myTeam" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="row p-4">
        <label>Team Name:</label>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@myTeam.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => myTeam.Name)" />
    </div>

    <div class="row p-4">
        <label>Team Game:</label>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@myTeam.Game" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => myTeam.Game)" />
    </div>

    <div class="row p-4">
        <label>Coach Name:</label>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@myTeam.Coach.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => myTeam.Coach.Name)" />
    </div>

    <div class="row p-4">
        <label>Coach's Favorite Game:</label>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@myTeam.Coach.FavoriteGame" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => myTeam.Coach.FavoriteGame)" />
    </div>

    <div class="row p-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

But during runtime, only the validation in class Team gets displayed...the validation of class Person gets skipped, and does not get invoked or displayed during runtime.

[image]

Is there a simple way of getting the ValidationMessageFor to work for class properties that are made of custom objects without getting into creating a  whole new custom validator or a custom ValidationMessageFor component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the blazor documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types

essentially you need to use the ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator in the blazor form, and [ValidateComplexType] attribute

Comment: Thank you thank you @AppPack for the very easy and simple solution and pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: Would it be better practice to use a View Model that has those fields / validations?

Answer (score 1):

Learning from documentation pointed by @AppPack, these are the only changes needed to make this work:

1. Install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation** (*prerelease*) package
2. Use **[ValidateComplexType]** on the complex property (*code sample below*)

   [ValidateComplexType]
   public Person Coach { get; set; }
3. Replace DataAnnotationsValidator with **ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator** in the razor page